# Validar checkbox de positivo a negativo en tabla

Tags: php, html, jquery

quiero colocar 0 o 1 si el checkbox de la fila esta seleccionada, funciona bien al pasarle el 1 pero eso es cuando esta chekcked, de otra forma no funciona para pasarle cero, ní poniendo `$(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputvalor').val("0");` con else.

```
var verificarTotal = function () {
        var $seleccionados = $(".chkseleccion:checked"),
            $cajas = $("#totalc"),
            $kilogramos = $("#totalp"),
            $t1 = $("#total1"),
            $t2 = $("#total2"),
            totalCajas = 0,
            totalKilogramos = 0;

        $.each($seleccionados, function (indice, fila) {
            if ($(fila).is(':checked')) {
                totalCajas += parseInt($(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputcajas').html());
                totalKilogramos += parseInt($(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputpeso').html());
                $(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputvalor').val("1");
            } else {
           $(fila).closest('tr').find('.inputvalor').val("0");
        }
        });


        $cajas.val(totalCajas);
        $kilogramos.val(totalKilogramos);
        $t1.text(totalCajas);
        $t2.text(totalKilogramos);

    };
```

¿Alguien sabe que esta pasando?

mi tabla :

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-buttons_info" style="width: 100%;">
                              <thead>
                                <tr role="row">
                                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="">#</th>
                                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="">Peso de tarima</th>
                                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="">Cajas de tarima</th>
                                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="">Enviar</th>
                              </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <?php if(!empty($tarimas)): ?>
                                        <?php foreach($tarimas as $tarimas): ?>
                                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                            <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">
                                                <input type="number" value="0" name='valores[]' class="inputvalor">
                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tarimas->id;?>" name='inputseleccion[]'><?php echo $tarimas->id; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputpeso"><?php echo $tarimas->peso; ?> kgs</td>
                                            <td class="inputcajas"><?php echo $tarimas->cajas; ?> cajas</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name='inputselect[]' class="chkseleccion"> Añadir
                                                </label>
                                                </div>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Creo que ayudaria si colocaras tu HTML

Comment: listo ya la he agregado

Comment: Trata de poner otro valor en el else, como 6 o lo que sea, solo para ver si funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
var $seleccionados = $(".chkseleccion:checked"),
```

Estas seleccionando solo lo valores que estan chequeados de la clase.  Simplemente remueve la ultima parte asi:

```
var $seleccionados = $(".chkseleccion"),
```

Comment: si imagine que fuera a ser algo muy simple pero no daba, gracias!